# Simple serial AVR programmer for beginner

Tags: embedded, avr, circuit

What is the cheap and good way to make a serial (RS232) programmer for AVR atMega and atTiny? There are several circuits in the Internet, but which one is better?

I'd like to be able to program my controller from Linux and Windows using some standard tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Serial port AVR programmer (DASA) Kit](http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=16&products_id=26) from Adafruit Industries. It's only $7.50, is very popular with the [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Introduction) community, and she provides step by step [instructions for assembly](http://www.ladyada.net/make/spokepov/makeserialdongle.html) on her personal site.

If you don't want to build it yourself, [Sparkfun Electronics](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/categories.php?c=1) has several serial programmers available for a bit more money.

Comment: I found the USBtinyISP to be very easy and quick to assemble too.  Never got around to trying to use it though.

Answer (score 2):

I've previously had good success using the (free!) [Pony Programmer](http://www.lancos.com/prog.html) software and dongle.
They provide schematics for the hardware, which was simple and seemed to do the trick.

Haven't used the linux version of the software for some time but the windows version seemed to do everything that it needed to.

Answer (score 1):

If usb can be used, I really don't think the original programmer ([AVR ISP mkII](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=3808)) is that expensive, the pricing today was about 34$.

Answer (score 1):

**http://onlinetps.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=65&products_id=188**
This Serial Port AVR Programmer is a serial port dongle compatible with PonyProg and other programming software. It does not require any external power supply; it takes power from your target board. The dongle attaches to your PC via a standard DB9 serial port
Information:

This Serial Port AVR Programmer Programmer is most inexpensive AVR programmer on the  market. It works with the great free AVR programming software - the Pony -Prog you can always look at the list of the supported devices on this link as it grows every month.

Supported Device

ATmega103, ATmega161, ATmega163, ATmega 323, ATmega128, ATmega8, ATmega16, ATmega8L, ATmega16L, ATmega64, ATmega32,ATmega64L, ATmega32L, ATmega162, ATmega169, ATmega8515, ATmega8535, ATtiny12, ATtiny15, ATtiny26, ATtiny2313,ATtiny13, 25, 45, 85, 261, 461
And lots  more..........

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitbang programming. All that you need is ftdi ft232 chip and avr-dude software.

http://easyelectronics.ru/img/readydev/FTDIBBProg/ftbb.JPG

http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/

Answer (score 1):

The [Bus Pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate) is one more USB option. It is actually a handy tool for a lot of (serial bus related) uses. It may not be as smooth or fast as dedicated programmers, though.